# Adding coordinates to DWG/DGN shapes. Conversion to KML- using them with Fusion Tables

Tags: maps, kml, google-fusion-tables, kmz, dwg

I have some regional maps from an open data directory (electoral districts; Barcelona, Spain; [link](http://w20.bcn.cat/opendata/Cataleg.aspx?lang=CAT&arbres=TERRITORI&formats=altres&q=censal&m=l&ti=1322759320659)). They are DWG or DGN shapes and polygons

I have found an online tool to convert these files to KML/KMZ files ([link](http://mygeodata.eu/apps/converter/index_en.html)).

So, what I don't know is how to fit these shapes in the coordinates of the region. In other words, how to georeference them.

What I want is to import these georeferenced shapes into Google Earth, as a first step to work with them in a Fusion Tables (tool I'm familiar with)

I'm a 'new' journalist, working with a Mac, used to work with designed tools as Illustrator. Familiar with Fusion Tables. I don't have Autocad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ogr2ogr to convert the dwg files to a kml, and then upload that.  See [Converting a CAD file to a shape file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409974/converting-a-cad-file-to-a-shape-file) for a related question, and add -f "KML" so your output file is in kml format rather than the default shapefile.